# promQL spike in time-series graphs

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am using springboot micrometer for prometheus and I have applied below promQL to draw the number of request recived at server end.

```
rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="$application", instance="$instance", status=~"2..",uri!~".*/health|.*/prometheus" }[1m])
```

when choose the time interval to 6h or 24h or 2day I am getting spikes even though the services are continuously getting request.

[image]

following is the promQL i m using

```
rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="$application", instance="$instance", status=~"2..",uri!~".*/health|.*/prometheus" }[1m])
```

I am expecting a continues graph inside of spikes as the time interval changes

Comment: I believe everything is OK with your graph. If you click on one of the spiking metrics in the legend, do you see it continuously (but with part between spikes sticking to the bottom)?

Comment: Do you have another source you can compare against? Logfiles for example?

Comment: Yes I checked the same in ALB data from cloudwatch. and that was flat

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus calculates `rate(m[d])` **independently** per each point displayed on the graph in Grafana. It calculates `rate(m[d])` at every point on the graph with the timestamp `t` in the following way:

1. For each [time series](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#time-series) matching the series selector `m` (see [filtering docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#filtering)) it selects all the [raw samples](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#raw-samples) on the time range `(t-d .. t]`.
2. For each time series it calculates the difference between the last and the first raw sample value on the time range `(t-d .. t]` and divides it by `d`.

Grafana automatically adjusts the duration between points on the graph (aka `$__interval`) depending on the selected time range (aka `$__range`). Usually it requests around 1000 points on the graph. So the duration between points on the graph can be roughly estimated as `$__range / 1000`.

If the selected time range doesn't exceed 1000 minutes (e.g. 17 hours), then `rate(...[1m])` takes into account all the [raw samples](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#raw-samples) on the time range, since the lookbehind window `[1m]` for [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) is bigger than the interval between points on the graph. But if the selected time range exceeds 17 hours, then `rate(...[1m])` will start skipping raw samples on the selected time range, since the interval between points on the graph exceeds `1m`. This may lead to unexpected results as in your case. There are the following solutions exist:

1. To consistently use `$__interval` inside `rate()` square brackets, so the distance between points on the graph always equals to the lookbehind window (e.g. `rate(...[$__interval])`. This guarantees that all the raw points are taken into account when building the graph on any time range. This solution has a drawback though - the graph will become smoother on bigger time ranges, since `rate()` calculates **average** increase rate on the given lookbehind window in square brackets.
2. To use [rollup_rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rollup_rate) function from [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics) - this is Prometheus-like project I work on. This function consistently returns min, max and avg rates on any selected time range. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832) for more details.